# How can I determine uniqueness of each line after a certain character?

Tags: list, sorting, uniq

I have an email list like this:

- name_1@domain.com
- name_2@domain.com
- name_1@domain_2.com
- name_1@domain_3.com
- name_2@domain_3.com
- name_1@domain_4.com

How can I remove all duplicate emails based upon domain? So in the example above, I would delete name_2@domain.com and name_2@domain_3.com.

I know how to use **uniq** but it doesn't seem to support skipping to the *@* char before determining uniqueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking down the problem, it looks like you want to retain only the first address for each domain.  To do that, you first get a unique list of domains, then use head to retain only the first of them.  Assuming you have those addresses one line at a time in a file called `unsorted.txt` this can be done with something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
DOMAINS=$(cut -d@ -f2 unsorted.txt | sort | uniq)
for DOMAIN in $DOMAINS ; do
    grep $DOMAIN unsorted.txt | head -1
done
```